# jQuery event calendar "cuts off" end date

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am using fullCalendar to display events from a mySQL database. The problem is when events are loaded the end date of each event gets "cut off". In the example shown on the picture event should be from 1st to 3rd, but it shows 1st to 2nd.

[image]

I have tried searching but I could not find anyone with similar problem and I checked database to see how it is stated there and it works correctly at that side (It is from 1st to 3rd)

```
<?php

//load.php
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=booker', 'root', '');

$data = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["ID"],
  'title'   => $row["username"],
  'start'   => $row["start_date"],
  'end'   => $row["end_date"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);
?>






<?php
//index.php
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Book</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.4.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: 'load.php',
    selectable:true,
    selectHelper:true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
     var title = prompt("Enter Event Title");
     if(title)
     {
      var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
      $.ajax({
       url:"insert.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{title:title, start:start, end:end},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Added Successfully");
       }
      })
     }
    },
    editable:true,
    eventResize:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function(){
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert('Event Update');
      }
     })
    },

    eventDrop:function(event)
    {
     var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
     var title = event.title;
     var id = event.id;
     $.ajax({
      url:"update.php",
      type:"POST",
      data:{title:title, start:start, end:end, id:id},
      success:function()
      {
       calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
       alert("Event Updated");
      }
     });
    },

    eventClick:function(event)
    {
     if(confirm("Are you sure you want to remove it?"))
     {
      var id = event.id;
      $.ajax({
       url:"delete.php",
       type:"POST",
       data:{id:id},
       success:function()
       {
        calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        alert("Event Removed");
       }
      })
     }
    },

   });
  });

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <br />

  <br />
  <div class="container">
   <div id="calendar"></div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I just need that blue line from picture to include an end date, in this case 3rd January. 
Kind Regards

Comment: Hey Ricky. Perhaps you can **A)** Show us a sample of what `load.php` returns, and **B)** slim down your code so that it's a **minimal** example. A good amount of it seems extraneous in regards to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your start_date and end_date fields contain dates and times, or just dates only?

If, as I suspect, they contain only dates, then fullCalendar will consider them "all-day" events. This means it will automatically set the time component of the `start` and `end` values of the event to midnight on the date given.

And since (as per the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object)) the end date is **exclusive**, this means that if you specify the 3rd as the end date, without any time, then your end date becomes the 3rd at midnight. And since that's an exclusive date (i.e. it's not considered part of the span of your event), your event is then considered to end on the 2nd at 23:59:59. And that's why it doesn't shown up on the 3rd.

---

Alternatively, if your end_date *does* contain a time, and that time is earlier in the day than the value of the [nextDayThreshold](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/nextDayThreshold) option, then that would, in a non-time-aware view such as "month", be a reason why your event would not extend into the 3rd. If you want to change that, then set a different value for `nextDayThreshold` in your calendar.

---

I've suggested both of these possibilities as you didn't provide us with the actual data values which are creating the output in your screenshot. Please follow whichever one is applicable to your situation.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your explanation. Start and end date only use dates not time. I understand what you wrote about midnight. Is there a way to fix it? I do not need time, but I would need to include that end date. Thank you one again for explaining!

Comment: Here's one option: http://jsfiddle.net/d905yja4/ . Here's another: http://jsfiddle.net/d905yja4/1/. Or another: http://jsfiddle.net/5ys72n93/ . You should make sure you're also happy with the appearance of the event in the "week" view as well, before making your decision. Obviously in all of these cases it will require you to use PHP to manipulate the data coming from the database before you provide it to fullCalendar.

Comment: Thanks for solutions. I saw what you did with time and on one you used end date as 4th. I use PHP scrip for load as you know since there are many events. I thought about adding +1 to end day in db (In this example 4th), but I can not do that since I need that data as it is. Start and end date fields are only date without time and I would not like to change that since it would make input process much more complicated. I was wondering is it possible to modify PHP load script without affecting data in db, also without affect data type for start and end date.

Comment: This is my load PHP script   `<?php

//load.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=booker', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["ID"],
  'title'   => $row["username"],
  'start'   => $row["start_date"],
  'end'   => $row["end_date"]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>`

Comment: " was wondering is it possible to modify PHP load script without affecting data in db"...of course it is.  Instead of just giving `$row["end_date"]` immediately into the "end" property, first you must parse it as a DateTime, add one day to it, and then format the result into a string again, which you then put into your array as the "end". https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php should help you. You can also find a lot on google about parsing, manipulating and formatting PHP datetimes.

Comment: Do I need to change field type in the database (for end_date)? I have tried using function date_format, but I always get error expected DateTimeInterface

Comment: I don't know - what type it is it now? Anyway you'd have to show me exactly what code you tried and exactly what error you get. I can't fix an incomplete error message on some invisible code :-)

Comment: Current field type for end_date is DATE (without time). This is one example of code I have tried:

Comment: `<?php

//load.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=booker', 'root', '');
$date="SELECT end_date FROM events";
$convert=date_format($date,"Y/m/d 23:59:00");
$data = array();

$query = "SELECT * FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["ID"],
  'title'   => $row["username"],
  'start'   => $row["start_date"],
  'end'   => $row[$convert]
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>`

Comment: Did you https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php? It makes clear that the date_format() function requires you to provide it with an _object_ which implements the `DateTimeInterface` interface, not just a plain string. The error is telling you that what you're inputting does not implement it. Of course a [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object does implement that interface. And as the same page notes, you can use [date_create()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) function to create a DateTime object from a (valid) string.

Comment: I have tried using date_create(), but I get the error "expects string, array given" even if I have used json_encode. With this code I have tried to fetch only end_date and convert it, but I got the error. Here is the code:

Comment: `<?php

//load.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=booker', 'root', '');

$data = array();

$query = "SELECT end_date FROM events ORDER BY id";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach($result as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(

  'end'   => $row["end_date"]
 );
}

json_encode($data);

$date = date_create($data);
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d 23:59:00');

?>
`

Comment: I don't understand why you put the end date into an array and then encoded it as JSON? What made you think of doing that?? Just pass the end date string from the database direct to the date_create method.

Comment: If it doesn't like the format the date is being supplied in, then use DateTime::createFromFormat to tell PHP how to parse it.

Comment: I have tried using it before this, but I still get two errors. Here is the code.

Comment: This is the part with errors `$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=booker', 'root', '');
$date="SELECT end_date from events";
$state=$connect->prepare($date);
$state->execute();
$result1=$state->fetchAll();
$new=date_create($result1);
$fin=date_format($new,'Y-m-d 23:59:00');`

Comment: When I use date_create function like this `date_create("2013-03-15");` it works, but soon as I assign $result1 as a variable, I get errors. It works when 1 date is added "manually".

Comment: As I'm sure you must realise really, $result1 is your whole result set, not a single field.  It's not even a single row. Think about what you are doing. You want to pass the **end date** to this function. Which variable represents the end date of each row? According to your earlier code, it's $row["end_date"]. So... `$new = date_create($row["end_date"]);` should be the code. I don't know why but your ability to think logically seems to have deserted you the last day or two??